# How to measure distance between elements in Electron? - pixel perfect Figma design

Tags: electron, google-chrome-devtools

In Firefox's devtools you can "Measure a portion of the page":

[image]

and then drag over the page:

[image]

This enables me to measure distances between elements, overall paddings, etc. How do I do this in an Electron app using Chrome devtools? Alternatively any other clever tips on how I can make sure my app matches the Figma design?

I could probs figure something out if not for the fact that you cannot use extra Chrome extensions...

Comment: Are you using Firefox Developer Edition? I don't have this measurement tool on FF 97.0.1 (Linux). Also, you can use Chrome DevTools extensions, take a look [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devtools-extension). Is that something feasible for you?

Comment: I think I might have enabled something extra somewhere in the options to have it visible (def. recommend btw ;) ). Good tip @AlexanderLeithner ! I've apparently been able to add `Dimensions` to my extensions. Console says it's been loaded, but I can't actually activate the tool using the shortcut for some reason. And without the shortcut I don't know how to activate it (I can't find an icon...)